# External librairy inside Air native extension for Android

Tags: android, adobe, external, libraries, ane

[RESOLVED]

Finally the problem was that my external lib use external jars. And the content of thoses jars also have to be in the extension jar. For example:

extension.jar have ton contain all the compiled classes of:

externallib.jar

externallib_referencing_external_lib.jar
[/RESOLVED]

First, I've been looking throught this topics

- [AIR 3 Native Extensions for Android - Can I/How to include 3rd party libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732742/air-3-native-extensions-for-android-can-i-how-to-include-3rd-party-libraries)
- [How to include additional Jar in Android Native Extension for Adobe Air Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626380/how-to-include-additional-jar-in-android-native-extension-for-adobe-air-mobile)

I got a similar problem. But not exactly the same. And the solution didn't worked for me :(.

First of all, I don't have any visible error.

-I can easily talk between java and action script.

-The gateway is set without problems.

My problem comes when, from my java-side-part of the extension, I try to call a 3rd party library. This library is (and I think this is where I do something  wrong) linked to my project as an external lib, in .jar format.

So when I make a call to 3rd party library, it just doesn't print anything. Neither on the adobe part or on the java part. The logs that are before my call are printed but not the ones after.

I tried different solutions that are:

-Taking all compiled class files of my external lib and add it inside the main native extension jar [link1]

same result (no errors)

-including the 3rd party jar inside the ANE by adding a dependence file that require the .jar [link2]

with this method i got this error that I don't get

> aapt tool failed:ERROR: input directory '--auto-add-overlay' does not exist

My third party library also include's itself some external .jars so do I need to include every jars inside the same packaged jar?

I can see that a lot of people are dealing with issues like that so my question would be:

What is the best way to include 3rd party library inside android AIR Native Extension ?.

For information, here is what I do to create the ANE

> adt -package -target ane AirInfinitGameANE\AirInfinitGame.ane AirInfinitGameASLib\src\extension.xml -swc AirInfinitGameANE\AirInfinitGameASLib.swc -platform Android-ARM -C AirInfinitGameLib .

- AirInfinitGameASLib: just the folder with the actionScript part and the config xml file
- AirInfinitGameANE: folder in the one that will be the native extension
- AirInfinitGameLib: the eclipse java project. I need to put in that folder the airInfinitgamelib.jar(extension jar) and the library.swf (from the swc file) in order to beeing able to compile the ANE.

Here it is ! Thanks a lot for thoses who'll read me.

Comment: Hi And Row ID, can you tell me how you resolved this issue ? I got the exact problem : no compile problem but no log either. The log is fine before calling the external jar function but don't show after (so I think it's silently crashing). Thanks !

Comment: Hello Plumillion Forge, look at the top of my post to see what I used to resolve my issue :)