# how can I know packagename, building an Android ANE

Tags: android, air, adobe, air-native-extension, ane

I'm trying to implement an external library ANE wrapper for Android.

I'm always receiving "class not found" error message in LogCat. No problem accessing native code, but when I try to access to external library functions it fails.

I've tried
[External library inside Air native extension for android](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1539959)
[How to include additional Jar in Android Native Extension for Adobe Air Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626380/how-to-include-additional-jar-in-android-native-extension-for-adobe-air-mobile)

Unsuccessfuly.
 Adobe Flash Platform * Including resources in your native extension package
Reading these docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2e74ffb4130044f3619-7ff8.html

I think I could have a problem loading the resources and, because of that, not access to the class properly or crashing somewhere.

My platformoptions.xml file

```
    <packagedDependencies>
        <packagedDependency>my_sdk.jar</packagedDependency>
    </packagedDependencies>
  <packagedResources>
  <packagedResource>
  <packageName>com.my_sdk</packageName>
  <folderName>res</folderName>
  </packagedResource>
  </packagedResources>
</platform>
```

My question is, how can I know the "packageName", "res" is the folder where I copied and pasted all the resources from the external library, but the package? I've just written randomly "com.my_sdk"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can unzip your jar file and explore derectories. For example you can find: com/google/gson/, so you should specify packageName tag as com.google.gson.

Or maybe you can look into javadoc for your library?

As for folderName tag. You should specify it as you call dir with resources of you library (if it's android lib). In case your lib just jar with some java code you should't specify packagedResource tag. And only write packagedDependency tag with jar name. E.g look at [here](https://github.com/crionuke/spy-ane/blob/master/dependencies/android/android-depends.xml)